# Looking for a Bible English to Hebrew word translation script

Tags: javascript, html, translation

This is for something I want to embed on my webpage.
A JavaScript or Webpage application that would work like this one.... https://av1611.com/verseclick/ But when you would mouseover a Bible word you could see the Hebrew word spelling and maybe even the meaning. This would help me a lot but I can't seem to find one. Otherwise I think I'm going to have to put links on each of the words myself. Thanks for any help.